# System.sobjectexception: sobject row was retrieved via soql without querying the requested field: Asset.Product2

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, soql

I have a problem on the query on my test class. I have put **AssetId__r.Product2Id** on the 1st query, and put **Product2Id** in the **Asset** query. but still the error persist. as the error says it needs **Asset.Product2** which is an SObject , not a field and I am lost on how to fix this error. does anyone encounter this error before? please I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would be easier if you'd post the actual query.

You probably have something like that in your code:

```
String name = myObject.AssetId__r.Product2.Name;
```

but the query `SELECT AssetId__r.Product2Id, ... FROM MyTable WHERE ...`

So what you can change is put more product fields in the query. You can go up to 5 dots "up".

```
SELECT AssetId__r.Product2.Id,
    AssetId__r.Product2.Name,
    AssetId__r.Product2.ProductCode
FROM myObject 
WHERE ...
```

It will work and then Apex that uses it can treat `AssetId__r.Product2` as a normal `Product2` object, as if it was queried separately. It'll have `Id, Name, ProductCode` fields set.

The query is also "safe". If AssetId__c is null or Product2Id is null - it'll still execute OK. You'll have to do null checks in Apex (or in query's WHERE clause)

Comment: The Product2Id is the lookup field for Product2, I will try this when I get back to work tomorrow, thank you.